# Can Microsoft Outlook Policy Tips be used in conjunction with add-ins REST/EWS send API?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins, policy, outlook-restapi

I have a scenario where a "compose mode" add-in for Outlook makes a subject line update to the draft email, then sends the email. The send action is currently carried out using either the EWS or REST APIs.

The issue occurs when a "override" policy tip is configured by the Exchange admin. The policy tip in question requires the user to choose override, in certain cases, to send an email (e.g external communication).

During message composition, if the appropriate trigger for the policy tip occurs, the policy tip appears and offers the user the option to override (as expected). When the add-in action is called, via ribbon button, the email appears to be sent. However, moments later an automated message from the Exchange indicates that the email has not been sent due to not adhering to the policy rule.

I believe this occurs because the send API, for both EWS and REST, does not call a local function in the Outlook client. Rather these API actually perform the send event on an email item syncedto and stored on the server. The Exchange server has no knowledge of the user's selection to override the policy tip at the client, so the issue occurs.

This happens in both Outlook on Desktop and Outlook Web Access.

I have searched through the EWS and REST APIs and cannot find any way to share/indicate the policy tip override when using these API.
I have searched the add-ins developer documentation and can find no mention of policy tips at all.
I have searched the Exchange admin policy tips documentation and can find no mention of add-ins compatibility or add-in related behavior.

So, can Microsoft Outlook Policy Tips be used in conjunction with add-ins REST/EWS send API?